# Why not use the root of the trie?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm trying to understand this program, why do they have to make `Trie* pCrawl = root`, why don't they just use the `root` of the tree and insert directly to it:

```
void insert(struct TrieNode *root, string key)
{
    struct TrieNode *pCrawl = root;
  
    for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++)
    {
        int index = key[i] - 'a';
        if (!pCrawl->children[index])
            pCrawl->children[index] = getNode();
  
        pCrawl = pCrawl->children[index];
    }
  
    // mark last node as leaf
    pCrawl->isEndOfWord = true;
}
```

Comment: Where do you have found this bad code? The function can invoke undefined behavior when root is equal to NULL.

Comment: Generally speaking, a variable named `root` should never represent something other than the root of the data structure imo. So the author copied it to a local variable for iteration purposes.

Comment: `void insert(struct TrieNode *root, string key)` -- Yet another horrid code example, where the coder can't make up their mind if they are writing C++ or C code.  The dead giveaway is the usage of `struct`, when in C++, there is no need to specify it there.

Comment: Bonus points for using string but the rest is what C programmers write. Drop all the `struct`. Use ranged-for and `new TrieNode()`.

Comment: It is just a good practice to not modify function augment. Some tools even enforce it. For compiler from final code point of view there is no difference (as-if rule).

Comment: And `root` should be `TrieNode &root` because passing `nullptr` would cause UB and is never needed. The reference would encode that fact in the signature leading to a safer interface. `const string &key` for performance reasons. Note: with `&root` the `pCrawl` thing makes sense again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `pCrawl` is needed.

The argument `root` is a copy of what is passed and modifying that won't affect the caller, so it is free to modify the value of `root` in the function.

It may be for clarity gained by using clear names for the argument (for input) and variable (for processing).

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow - U wot m8? "Broken" code is something that is guaranteed to crash and burn, this here is simply a stylistic choice (that is *very* debatable, despite the fact some developers think there's their opinion and the wrong opinion).